# How to use Minecraft LAN worlds in 1.8.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you find your ip? I know how to do the cmd and ipconfig but it isn't working? It always says 'Media Disconnected' where the ip should be. Help?

Comment: If you're going to ask a new question, use the Ask Question link, like you did.  You don't need to add it to your existing question.  Therefore, I have rolled back your additional question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know your local IP address. Minecraft LAN servers are automatically detected by other active Minecraft clients. It'll even show you the local network IP on MC for you.

[image]

(the bit before the `:` is the local IP address, the bit after the `:` is the port number)

Simply activating the LAN world inside the network should suffice.

Comment: Don't forget LAN Bukkit servers :P